# What does * mean on web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger

[image]

I am studying Udaru and on Swagger Web API there is * on resource here. i would like to know what does this mean ?

Answer (score 1):

This should be a wildcard. This means that you can call URL such as:

```
/authorization/access/1/hello/a/b/c/d
```

And `resource` variable will then be `a/b/c/d` in the action method.